# mySQL with PDO for not existing query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, left-join

I have two tables:

```
Table1      Table 2
C_ID        ID
user_ID     Title
```

Table1 is a list of users (user_ID) with entries for a contest (C_ID is the contest).

Table 2 is a list of contests (ID is ID of contest).

I am using the query below to find for a specific user which contests they do not have entries for. I am using PDO php/mysql.

```
"SELECT title, ID FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON A.ID=B.c_ID WHERE B.C_ID is null and B.user_ID=:user_ID"
```

If I take out the user filter, I correctly find contests that no one has entered.

If I take out the is null filter, I correctly find all contests that a certain user has entered.

However if I do them in together, I do not get contests that user has not entered.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Try joining Table2 to Table1 with `ON A.ID!=B.c_ID` or just select Table2 and `WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT C_ID FROM Table1)`

Comment: You are searching for all contests that no one has entered and that your user has entered. This query should return no rows.

Comment: Thanks @mim Your second method worked. I know it's not idea performance wise, but it works!